MLRun deploy_function returns cannot submit deploy, 404 Client Error
I am following the tutorial from this page Quick start tutorial
Everything works fine until I reach the project.deploy_function(serving_fn)
The call returns the following error:
error submitting nuclio deploy task: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects/first-project-xxx/nuclio/serving/deploy: details: Not Found, caused by: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/projects/first-project-xxx/nuclio/serving/deploy


MLRun is installed on Docker. I can access the following components:
MLRun UI (in http://localhost:8060)
Nuclio Dashboard/controller (in http://localhost:8070)
MLRun API (in http://localhost:8080) --> returns {"detail":"Not Found"}
I run the tutorial code in my IDE and I can see the project in the MLRun UI. Everything seems to work fine but when it comes to serving a function using the deploy_function it fails with the above error.
I could not find the API documentation (schema like openAPI) to see if the /api/v1/projects path is valid.
It would be very nice if someone could tell me what's wrong with the configuration or what is supposed to be the API call that would work.
Thank you!

When you call the : project.deploy_function(serving_fn), what are the logs from Docker ?

Hi Arnaud
The logs from docker for the MLRun API service are:

mlrun-api-1  | > 2024-05-10 12:06:04,551 [debug] Sending response: {'status_code': 404, 'request_id': '464a847d-293b-4c9f-b01e-80f90643674b', 'elapsed_time_in_ms': 7.615742, 'uri': '/api/v1/projects/first-project-arnaud/nuclio/serving/deploy', 'method': 'POST', 'headers': MutableHeaders({'host': 'localhost:8080', 'user-agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0 mlrun/1.7.0-rc15', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'accept': '/', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-mlrun-client-version': '1.7.0-rc15', 'x-mlrun-client-python-version': '3.9.19', 'content-length': '1100', 'content-type': 'application/json'})}
